# Docker Rest API '404 NOT FOUND'

Tags: docker

I am using the Docker rest api to build images, and then create and run containers. I can successfully build the image, but when I make the call to create a container I'm getting a '404 not found' response, with no other information. How can I debug this?

Request:

```
Method: POST,
RequestUri: 'https://myhost:2376/v1.21/containers/create?name=mycontainer',
Version: 1.1, 
Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, 
Headers:
{
   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
   Content-Length: 232
 }}
```

json:

```
{
  "Image":"myimage",
  "ExposedPorts":{"80/tcp":null},
  "Env":[
          "ENV_1=xxx",
          "ENV_2=xxxxx"
        ],
  "HostConfig: {
                 "Links":null,
                 "Env":null,
                 "PortBindings":null,
                 "RestartPolicy":{"Name":"always"},
                 "Binds":["myvol:/var/lib/myvol"]
               }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code? 404 not found means the API you sent the request to doesn't exist, or at least the way you implemented it.

Comment: thanks, I've added  my request to the question. I have successfully made this call to a different server before though, so I have a feeling there is some sort of cache or broken image/container somewhere.

Comment: Does myhost represent a localhost server?